# In MVN Repository, How do people find how to use library? (Spring, Java)

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've added dependency like this to use mysql connection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnCKf.png)

And I got to know that libraries are from MVN Repository
I searched for Docs but it wan't there

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw4lD.png)

How do people find how to use library in MVN Repository?

I have searched in Google, Youtube
And lots of info were 'How to install from MVN Respository' and 'Example codes'

I want 'How to find Docs'

Comment: question is: what did you search? A lot of the libraries documentation can be easily found by typing the name of the library + javadocs or documentation

Answer (score 1):

Each library has it's own site where you can find the documentation of that library. The Maven repository is just the deposit where Maven downloads open-source libraries from. If you need the documentation of Spring, just search for "Spring documentation".